# Save As To Prompt For Location But Use Filename From Cell

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I got this code from a forum and it works but I need to tweak it to show me the "save as" box but I with the name already populated with my variable FName.

Can someone help me with this?

```
Sub Save_New()
Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String
'FPath = "C:"
FName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Application.GetSaveAsFilename method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename) for that …

```
Option Explicit

Sub Save_New()
    Dim FName As String
    FName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text

    Dim DialogResult As Variant 'variant is needed because the dialog returns FALSE if users presses cancel.
    DialogResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFilename:=FName)

    If Not DialogResult = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DialogResult
    Else
        'user clicked cancel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I got an error "Compile error: Named argument not found" the code stops at the (InitialFilename:=FName) part of the code

Comment: @MEC Sorry had a typo in it: InitialFil**a**name should be InitialFil**e**name of course. Fixed it.

Comment: OMG, I didn't notice it either, works like a champ, thanks